# How can I detect a USB disconnect event? (Windows, .NET C# application)

Tags: .net, events, usb, disconnect

Currently how I do this is I poll for a masked list of USB devices (masked specifically for the device I'm working with) and if it's there, I continue, if not then I notify the user that the device is not connected.  The method for getting a list of USB devices is provided for me through a USB peripheral controller chip manufacturer's .NET library.

Is there an event somewhere for a USB device disconnect?

Comment: I made a NuGet packet that works on Windows, MacOS and Linux: https://github.com/Jinjinov/Usb.Events

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I ended up using this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363480(VS.85).aspx

And followed this: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/DriveDetector.aspx

Answer (score 3):

have you checked out the Win32_USBControllerDevice class?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394505(VS.85).aspx

Comment: I should clarify;  I'm actually using a USB peripheral controller chip (big difference, should've worded that better)

I'll look into that class, thanks Jose.

Also, I did find this too: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363480(VS.85).aspx  WM_DEVICECHANGE