# How to detect USB camera disconnected using WMI events in c#?

Tags: c#, wmi

I have a DSLR camera connected to my PC via a USB tether. My application can control the camera (change settings, take pictures, download images, etc.) When I power the camera on or off, or connect or disconnect the USB cable, my PC give an audible indication that the camera access has changed. How can I detect these changes in my application? I have seen various answers mentioning System.Management namespace, but haven't been able to find information on what classes, methods, options, etc. to use to accomplish what I need.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I detect a USB disconnect event? (Windows, .NET C# application)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541765/how-can-i-detect-a-usb-disconnect-event-windows-net-c-sharp-application)

Comment: @Sinatr Not really. It might if I knew how to translate Powershell to C#, and if I could see what was contained in the virus-infected .zip files from the CodeProject article.